# Procedure not allowed to query msdb.dbo.sysjobs but account can

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I'm not an expert DBA and I've tried googeling plenty. Here's the scenario.

This customer runs several databases on this server and we are not allowed to have the sysadmin fixed serverrole for our account.

Essentially this is happening.

1. Someone presses a button which in turn fires up procedure A.
2. Procedure A runs procedure B (which is looking for a particular SQLSA job) and we get an error.
3. Step three would be that procedure B tries to check if this particular SQLSA job is running and if not starts it.

However, we never make it to step 3.

Procedure B has the following code.

```
SELECT @job_id = job_id 
      FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj 
      WHERE  sj.name = @job
```

This gives the following error.

```
Msg 50000, Level 14, State 1, Procedure sp_startAgentJobAndWait, Line 151
Error 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure sp_startAgentJobAndWait, Line 36, Message: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobs', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
```

However, If I log into the same SQL account and query msdb.dbo.sysjobs it works.

I need to help their IT find the specific permissions they need to add for this to work.

The next interesting codeblocks the procedure B will run are

```
INSERT INTO @xp_results 
      EXECUTE master.dbo.Xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 


EXEC @r = msdb..Sp_start_job
```

I guess there might be problems with this too? If anyone is super good at dealing with permissions your advice or help is much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, also forgot to add I've tried running the procedures with the "WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER" AND "WITH EXECUTE AS N'<account'" option

Comment: What account is the application using to query SQL Server?

Comment: SQL account, no windows authentication.